# How can I use select with where condition in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter while using where statement I have following error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: a numbered reference must not be zero at offset 34

Filename: database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 1543

Backtrace:

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\manojgame\application\models\Main_model.php
Line: 34
Function: where

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\manojgame\application\controllers\Games.php
Line: 21
Function: select_data_bytitle

File: D:\xampp\htdocs\manojgame\index.php
Line: 262
Function: require_once
```

And my statement is :

```
$this->db->select('*');

$this->db->from('games');

$this->db->where('cat_type',1);

$query = $this->db->get();

if ( $query->num_rows() > 0 ) {
    $row = $query->row_array();
    return $row;
}
```

if I have remove

```
$this->db->where('cat_type',1);
```

code is running perfect.
How can I use where condition ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will help you to sort your problem

```
    $this->db->where('games',1); //----> you can pass variable instead of 1
    $query = $this->db->get('games');
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->row_array();
    }
    return false;
```

Hope this will help...

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

```
query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM  games WHERE cat_type = 1")->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Codeigniter [Active record](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html) (modified PHP Query to prevent SQL Injection)

```
//EXAMPLE: SELECT * FROM  games WHERE cat_type = 1
$query = $this->db->select('*')->get_where('games', array('cat_type' => '1'));

//EXAMPLE with condition: SELECT * FROM  games WHERE cat_type != 1
/*
$query = $this->db->select('*')->get_where('games', array('cat_type !=' => '1'));
*/

if($query->result()){ 
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
#do something here to get value of another rows or etc
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('cat_type',1);
$query = $this->db->get('games');
```

This will work perfectly

Let me know if you require any further help

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('games');
    $this->db->where('cat_type=1');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
```